# Fixed row in SSRS Child Group

Tags: reporting-services, static, toggle, parent-child

Hi below is an image of my report which utilizes a toggle. The toggle data is only one row which will then contain 50+ records, as well as column headers for that data.

I am wondering if there is a way to Fix these (sub) column headers after they have been toggled open?

I can get the first row Fixed, and when using the same techniques on the Child Group I receive the message:

> *The tablix 'Tablix1' has an incorrectly set FixedData property. FixedData is not allowed to be set on row TablixMember, unless it is also set on the first row.*>

But, when it is set on both rows, neither of them act as though they are Fixed Data :/

I don't even need the first row fixed but if anybody has suggestions please help!

Below is a link to a picture of the report, you'll notice the yellowish row with my toggle, and i would like the column headers below that to be fixed. Is this possible??

https://www.flickr.com/photos/125488420@N02/14450152092/

The row groups below: (**I KNOW ABOUT (Static) vs Static**.. This image is of the original version.  *Please* just note which rows should be **Static** headers, please done make that the only content of your response)
That said, I think my grouping is the issue, but I'm struggling to get it the way I want

https://www.flickr.com/photos/125488420@N02/14450154942/in/photostream/

Comment: I would give up on "toggles" as the user experience is rubbish. I prefer Bookmarks and/or the Document Map.

Comment: I  would also refactor your dataset design - Felony Arrests / Misd Arrests etc should be values in a Grouping column, with Total Arrests as a higher level Group.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer, though it is not what I'd hoped for.

> Firstly, in order to have a static row, the first row must ALSO be static.
>   Further, any static rows need to be "Contiguous" meaning that there cannot be a gap between them (ie rows 1-3 is ok but not rows 1 & 3 only)..

I experimented with some workarounds such as using multiple tablixs, row groupings, etc.
And in the end it was unsuccessful, and not worth continued effort. Unfortunately users will not be able to have the headers follow them down.  :(

If somebody has a solution or Non-Contiguous Fixed data is allowed in future releases please post!